# How can I draw a point at my ImagevView's anchorpoint?

Tags: ios, view

I am trying to achieve some effect using imageViews and I need to set the anchorpoint correctly. It is very hard without it being visible.
How would you go about showing it up on the imageview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor point is a property specified on the layer (you will need QuartCore to access it). It is specified in the unit coordinate space of the device (both x and y goes from 0 to 1 within the bounds of the layer. You can know the coordinate of the actor point by multiplying the x value with the width and the y value with the height. To draw a point at that location you could just add a new, small layer (bounds 4x4 and corner radius 4 (to get a circle))

Be aware that changing the anchor point will change where the layer (and the view) appears on screen as the frame is calculated relative to the anchor point. To have the frame appear in the same place after the anchor point has been set you could re-set the frame (this will update the layers position so that the frame is what you expect it to be)